# How can I retrieve data with only a revision id from CouchDB?

Tags: couchdb

I have only rev id and now I want to retrieve data by rev id in the Couch Db.

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/q/54947820/13860

Comment: I have rev number only and with that number I want to fetch the data. That's all

Comment: How did you end up with a rev id, but no doc id???

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So you wish to fetch any document that has a specific _rev, regardless of its _id. Leaving aside the obvious "why???" here, there is nothing in the CouchDB API that supports this, as the rev is not intended to be used without a corresponding id.

But if you *really* want to do this, I guess you could create a view that emits the _rev as the key and then query the view:

```
function (doc) {
   emit(doc._rev, 1);
}
```

But note: this is a really bad idea.

Comment: OK, but i am not that much good in couch db. Can you please provide me the method to create the view ?

Comment: Can you first explain why you have a rev but not the id?

Comment: I think with rev I can retrieve the data but after that I am not do that and now I have some data with only rev.

Comment: I've added the map function to create a view keyed on rev.

Comment: I think you need to read up a bit on how views work, e.g. from https://docs.couchdb.org/en/stable/ddocs/views/intro.html -- but you can enter the map function directly in fauxton (the couchdb dashboard), which is what I did to test out the above.